# Auto copy depending on date selected

Tags: google-sheets, calendar, formula

I want automatically to copy the contents of Sheet 1 to Sheet 2 depending on the selected date. Example, if I select June 4 on the calendar on Sheet 2, it will automatically display the contents on 6/4 Column on Sheet 1.

Any ideas?

See [sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XJkewJeHW6H18LaK6gdykSvUqieak0kuzY7g7shnjG8/edit?usp=sharing) wherein Data on Sheet 1 should reflect on Sheet 2 once the date is selected.
[image: Sheets 1 and 2]

Answer (score 0):

In Sheet2!B4 please try:

```
=query({Sheet1!$B4:$H8},"select Col"&match(B3,Sheet1!3:3,0))
```